# Django rest framework: redirect if unauthenticated for browsable API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm not sure how to implement a redirect to login if the user is doesn't meet the permissions criteria, as the documentation states: "Before running the main body of the view each permission in the list is checked." - so overriding methods in the view is fruitless.  If anyone could point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django Rest Framework is a toolkit to build web APIs. It doesn't render pages filled with content - it just serializes and sends the information which you requested. And in case you don't have the permission to access a resource on server, DRF sends you either a `401 Unauthorized` status, or a `403 Forbidden` status responses.

In order to redirect a user to the login page, you should do this in the frontend, after receiving a `401` status, which means that the user is not authenticated.