# Django rest framework redirect if permission denied

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I am new in Django-rest-framework. I am learning about authentication and permissions. I am getting stuck at one point.

I have created [custom permission](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) for selected users. So if some user doesn't have the correct permission for some view class, it returns HTTP status-**403**. In the browser it has message **"403 Forbidden"**. Instead of this, I want to redirect the user to some other page.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: rest-framework most usage for create an `api` that shouldn't do resirect.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191780/django-rest-framework-redirect-if-unauthenticated-for-browsable-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django rest framework: redirect if unauthenticated for browsable API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191780/django-rest-framework-redirect-if-unauthenticated-for-browsable-api)